# Should a tag be split for platform specific editions of a library?

Tags: discussion, tags

My case in point is my proposed tag 'jqGrid-mvc', in addition to the existing tag 'jqGrid', to narrow question focus to Trirand's *jqGrid ASP.NET MVC* product, versus their general jqGrid range, which also includes *jqGrid PHP* and *jqGrid ASP.NET WebForms* variants.

There is an existing 'jqGrid ASP.NET tag', which could include both *jqGrid ASP.NET MVC* and *jqGrid ASP.NET WebForms* products, but most questions tagged with this tag appear to address web forms related problems. I think it is significant to our taxonomy that these two products are quite different are never used together or interchangeably in a single project.

My main board question that prompted this question is: [Where can I start looking for a null reference that causes an exception when trying to databind an MVC jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365101/where-can-i-start-looking-for-a-null-reference-that-causes-an-exception-when-try)

Comment: Good Lord.  How about just [jqGrid], with an additional tag for the base system, i.e. ASP.NET MVC or PHP or ASP.NET Webforms?  Your example question is tagged perfectly.

Comment: Good point on the additional tag only for the base system, but my point above was seeing as there already is a more explicit 'tag level' for jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am still green or not quite clear on the question but isn't it enough to just add the individual tags that apply to a question?

For example: [reactor](/questions/tagged/reactor)[php](/questions/tagged/php) or [reactor](/questions/tagged/reactor)[coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion) depending on which flavour of the Reactor framework you are inquiring about.

More specific to your case my example would be [jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid)[mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc)[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net).

Comment: Happy to receive your downvotes on this if I am off base (I've been trying to figure out the complexities of the tagging system lately). Just please provide some info as to why I am incorrect if that is the case.

Comment: Good point on the additional tag only for the base system, but my point above was seeing as there already is a more explicit 'tag level' for jqGrid, being 'jqgrid-asp.net'.

The combo you propose doesn't distinguish between questions about the foss jqgrid jQuery extension, and the paid for WebForms and MVC .net libraries, and I think it's quite an important distinction.